# When deleting a lot of text via backspace, Thunderbird freezes

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

So I open a gmail message in thunderbird (imap account), and want to delete a lot of text. I keep pressed the `backspace` button and deleting starts. But maybe after 5 or 10 deleted characters, thunderbird freezes and I have to release backspace button.

does anyone know why this happens and how to fix this?

I use Thunderbird 17.0.5 on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not selecting the text you want to delete and hit backspace only once? This saves you time when deleting a lot of text at the same time. If you really want to use the keyboard, hold shift and use the arrow keys to select the tekst you want to delete. Then also you need to hit backspace only once.

Comment: Ah you use Ubuntu.. Not sure if keyboard combinations work for that, but it might be worth a try :)

Comment: @Forza I know those tricks. It happens even when I want to delete 1 whole word.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug in Thunderbird.  I would report this bug to Mozilla.  This isn't a IMAP issue since everything is in a local cache.